# Spark on Kubernetes: cannot run program "python3"

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I created a spark image with python environment using the example from the official documentation, but it cannot run the official example script in the kubernetes cluster.

create image:

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r pyspark -t 3.3.1-2 -p ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build
```

Submit tasks to the cluster

```
./bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://172.16.0.6:6443 --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=techcool \                                                         
    --name spark-pi \       
    --conf spark.executor.instances=5 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=pyspark/spark:3.3.1-2 \
    local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

always get an error:

```
 + exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=10.244.36.87 --deploy-mode client --properties-file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py

 23/05/24 09:02:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": error=2, No such file or directory
```

I'm pretty sure the python3 interpreter exists. I can run the image directly and it works fine:

```
docker run -it --rm pyspark/spark-py:3.3.1-2 driver --class org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner local:///opt/spark/examples/src/main/python/pi.py
```

I tried specifying environment variables, but it didn't work:

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 \
--conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 1):

ok... I found the cause... I passed wrong image to `spark-submit`... should pass `pyspark/spark-py` instead of `pyspark/spark`.

`spark-py` and `spark` are the image names automatically added when using docker-image-tool.sh to build the image.

eg.

```
./bin/docker-image-tool.sh -r myspark -t 3.3.1-2 -p ./kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/bindings/python/Dockerfile build
```

Two images will be created: `myspark/spark`, `myspark/spark-py`